# How to compare NSDates to find earliest and latest dates in an array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I'm having a lot of problems with my code that determines the earliest date and latest date in an array. Here is the code I'm using:

```
NSDate *startDate = nil; // Earliest date
NSDate *endDate = nil; // Latest date

for (id entry in myArray) 
{
    NSDate *date = [entry objectForKey:kDate];

    if (startDate == nil && endDate == nil) 
    {
        startDate = date;
        endDate = date;
    }
    else if ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        startDate = date;
    }
    else if ([date compare:startDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
    {
        endDate = date;
    }

    date = nil;
}
```

Please can someone help me work out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surely you're setting `startDate` and `endDate` the wrong way round in the `else if` statements? Don't you want this:

```
NSDate *startDate = nil; // Earliest date
NSDate *endDate = nil; // Latest date

for (id entry in myArray) 
{
    NSDate *date = [entry objectForKey:kDate];

    if (startDate == nil && endDate == nil) 
    {
        startDate = date;
        endDate = date;
    }
    if ([date compare:startDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        startDate = date;
    }
    if ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
    {
        endDate = date;
    }

    date = nil;
}
```

Comment: Since the comparison of `date` to `endDate` has nothing to do with the result of the comparison of `date` to `startDate` you have to remove the `else` too. Probably get rid of both.

Comment: Eek yes I totally glossed over that bit. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Think again and put the `else`'s back in. (`date` cannot both be after the `endDate` and before `startDate`!)

Answer (score 11):

Also you can sort `NSArray` with `NSDates` with method:

```
array = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Then at `[array firstObject]` will be first date (e.g. 1970-01-01T00:00:00), and last object: `[array lastObject]` will be last date: (e.g. 2011-01-12T00:00:00)

Answer (score 3):

You may also use the pre-defined [`distantPast`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`distantFuture`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) constants to avoid the extra check for `nil`:

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate distantFuture];
NSDate *endDate = [NSDate distantPast];

for (id entry in myArray)
{
    NSDate *date = [entry objectForKey:kDate];

    if ([date compare:startDate] == NSOrderedAscending) { startDate = date; }
    if ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending)  { endDate = date; }

    date = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `earlierDate:` and `laterDate:` NSDate functions

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate distantFuture];
NSDate *endDate = [NSDate distantPast];

for (id entry in myArray) 
{
    NSDate *date = [entry objectForKey:kDate];
    startDate = [startDate earlierDate:date];
    endDate = [endDate laterDate:date];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for other similar problems: the `valueForKeyPath:` option is very neat I think:

```
[myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"];
[myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"];
```

This assumes the object in the array implement the `compare:` method the way you want it. I use it to get the earliest date in an array of dates for example. If you would like to use it here, the objects in the array should override the `compare:` method though.

Answer (score 0):

The earliest date might be found by using the standard algorithm to fine min/max value in array:

```
NSMutableArray<NSDate *> *allDates; // dates array
NSDate *earliestDate = allDates.firstObject;
        for (NSDate *date in allDates) {
            if ([date compare:earliestDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
                earliestDate = date;
            }
        }
```

To find the latest date in array use `NSOrderedDescending` instead of `NSOrderedAscending`.